# Valgrind is reporting "Use of uninitialised value of size 4" when using strlen

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, valgrind

I'm trying to use Valgrind on Raspberry Pi. I am analyzing the following program:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    std::string blaat = "blaat";
    const char * buf = blaat.c_str();
    size_t l = 0;
    l = strlen(buf);
    printf("string size %u\n", l);
}
```

Compile:

```
g++ -g -Wall -O0 test.cpp
```

Analyze (valgrind-3.16.1):

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./a.out
```

Result:

```
==29572==
==29572== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==29572==    at 0x4866210: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so)
==29572==
==29572== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==29572==    at 0x48662DC: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so)
==29572==
==29572== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==29572==    at 0x4AABF6C: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==29572==    by 0x4AB0727: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==29572==    by 0x4AB646F: printf (printf.c:33)
==29572==    by 0x1088F: main (test.c:10)
==29572==
==29572== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==29572==    at 0x4AABF74: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==29572==    by 0x4AB0727: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==29572==    by 0x4AB646F: printf (printf.c:33)
==29572==    by 0x1088F: main (test.c:10)
==29572==
==29572== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==29572==    at 0x4AAF8FC: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==29572==    by 0x4AB646F: printf (printf.c:33)
==29572==    by 0x1088F: main (test.c:10)
==29572==
==29572== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==29572==    at 0x4AAF99C: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==29572==    by 0x4AB646F: printf (printf.c:33)
==29572==    by 0x1088F: main (test.c:10)
==29572==
==29572== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==29572==    at 0x4AAFA00: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==29572==    by 0x4AB646F: printf (printf.c:33)
==29572==    by 0x1088F: main (test.c:10)
==29572==
==29572== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==29572==    at 0x4AAFA7C: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==29572==    by 0x4AB646F: printf (printf.c:33)
==29572==    by 0x1088F: main (test.c:10)
```

Once I use "strlen" Valgrind seems to give me warnings about uninitialized values. Why?

Comment: Does it matter if you do use `%zu` which is for size_t, instead of `%u` for unsigned int?  Alternatively, `static_cast<unsigned int>(l)`.

Comment: Both alternatives did not change the Valgrind output - still getting warnings

Comment: assuming you want to silence them:   https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Valgrind_Suppression_File_Howto

Comment: This is just how glibc on ARM works, i get this errors all the time. I assume it is for performance reasons. Pages always align to a multiple of 4 bytes so it does normally not hurt to check 4 bytes at once for `strlen()`. Us the valgrind suppression as a work around.

Comment: The output of strlen is used eg. as a parameter to sendbuffer(data, sz) function. Now Valgrind will also report that this function is using unititialized bytes. So instead of adding strlen to the suppressions file I have to add sendbuffer to the suppressions file. However these functions are the ones which I want to check.

Comment: the code is perfectly fine (except for needing `%zu`)